# ant build issue in Maximo Anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am getting below error during ant build after running rdf puller.

[java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.tivoli.si.build.rdf.dictionary.NotExistOSLCFieldException: type in [http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#ResAnywhereResource]

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the RDFs prior to build. Please refer the solution mentioned in the below link.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21690466

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by running rdf-puller:

ant -f anywhere-rdfs-puller.xml -Dadapter.connection.user= -Dadapter.connection.password=